# Getting error Nonetype in python 2.7

Tags: python, mongodb

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is there something wrong with the following script? I am using get() in the script because of some phone field names missing in Mongodb collections.

The sample data:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("57e99f88b948da6c3be04366"),
    "email": "jstahl2020@gmail.com",
    "phone": [
        {
            "type": "Mobile",
            "number": "250-851-1041"
        }
    ]}
```

the python script :

```
import codecs
import csv
cursor = db.users.find ({}, {'_id':1, 'email': 1, 'phone.type':1, 'phone.number':1})
with codecs.open('applicatonmethod3.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:        
        fields = ['_id', 'email', 'phone.type', 'phone.number'] 
        write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
        write.writeheader()    
        for x in cursor:
            x_id = x.get('_id')
            x_email = x['email']            
            y = x.get('phone')            
            z = {'_id': x_id,
                'email': x_email,
                'phone.type': y.get('type'),
                'phone.number': y.get('number')}                               
            write.writerow(z)
```

please someone can help me.

Comment: Run it through a debugger or print things. For starters, `print(x)` just inside the for loop.

Comment: The error means that `x` is `None`, which means `cursor` contains `None`. Figure out why that is happening.

Comment: I checked data in the collection that there are not phone field name in some rows. that is why I use get() to skip them. thanks

Comment: It's not the field that's missing, it's the record itself.

Comment: do you have any idea to fix the problem? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you connected to the correct database, the one that contains the users collection and not just the default database?

Comment: yes, I connected to the correct database by using pymongo.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262024 follow this link it may help you not sure,just give a try

Comment: it worked after changed y = x.get('phone') to  for y in x.get('phone', {}):  but I got the repeated rows. Can someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the problem.  I just share it with you. here is the solution. thanks you for help.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
import codecs
import csv
cursor = db.users.find ({}, {'_id':1, 'phone.type':1, 'phone.number':1, 'phone.extension':1})
with codecs.open('phone.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:        
        fields =['_id', 'phone.type', 'phone.number', 'phone.extension'] 
        write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
        write.writeheader()    
        for x in cursor:
            x_id = x['_id']                                        
            for y in x.get('phone', {}):                                                                        
                z = {'_id': x_id,                                    
                    'phone.type': y.get('type'),
                    'phone.number': y.get('number'),
                    'phone.extension': y.get('extension')}
                print z                                                                                              
                write.writerow(z) 

cursor.close()
```